# How to multiply numbers in java keeping specific precision?

Tags: java, math, floating-point, double, precision

I have java program which multiplies numbers and I need EPSILON which represents expected precision in floating-point calculations
I have EPSILON = 1e-10;

```
double x = 0.19334657881077877;
if (x == ( x* 1e8) * 1e-8)
    System.out.println("true");
else System.out.println("false");
```

this always prints false
How can I do the multiply so that it prints true?

Comment: Why are you not using the epsilon?

Answer (score 1):

float and double are both using binary to compute the value, they will lose some data while computing and between the conversion of binary and decimal.

You should try using BigDecimal to avoid this situation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x = 0.19334657881077877;
        if (x == x * 1e8 * 1e-8) {
            System.out.println("true");
        } else {
            System.out.println("false");
        }
        System.out.println(x * 1e8);
        System.out.println(x * 1e-8);
        System.out.println(x * 1e8 * 1e-8);

        BigDecimal y = new BigDecimal("0.19334657881077877");
        if (y.equals(y.multiply(new BigDecimal("1e8")).multiply(new BigDecimal("1e-8")))) {
            System.out.println("true");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("false");
        }
        System.out.println(y.multiply(new BigDecimal("1e8")));
        System.out.println(y.multiply(new BigDecimal("1e-8")));
        System.out.println(y.multiply(new BigDecimal("1e8")).multiply(new BigDecimal("1e-8")));
    }
```